# How to spread objects into array?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

How to correctly push objects into array like spread-operator do with non-objects:

I need:

```
state.selected = [state.selected, ...action.payload] // Type 'object' is not an array type.
```

I tried:

```
userSelect(state, action: PayloadAction<object>){
                  state.selected.concat(action.payload)
        }
```

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<WritableDraft>[]): WritableDraft[]', gave the following error.     Argument of type 'object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<WritableDraft>'.       Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ConcatArray<WritableDraft>': length, join, slice   Overload 2 of 2, '(...items: (WritableDraft | ConcatArray<WritableDraft>)[]): WritableDraft[]', gave the following error.     Argument of type 'object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WritableDraft | ConcatArray<WritableDraft>'

**P.S.:**

Why `array.push(obj)` here return array length ?

Comment: In response to the question: _Why array.push(obj) here return array length ?_, please [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to understand what `.push()` does and what it returns. Specifically, please [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value) what it returns.

Comment: When you've added a tag, repeating that in the question title is useless noise. I've removed that noise from your post title.  The tagging system here works very well, and it doesn't need any help.

Comment: could you provide an example of the object values? you probably have to loop through the object and append it to the array.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood problem correctly, you are spreading the wrong variable. Currently you are spreading `action.payload`.

Try this:

```js
userSelect(state, action: PayloadAction<object>){
      return [...state.selected, action.payload] 
}
```

What this does is first copy all the items in `state.selected`, then it adds `action.payload` to the new array, and finally returns that new array.

Comment: I am using Redux ToolKit, therefore I need to reassign state instead of simply return value

Comment: Even if you want to modify properties in state you should not mutate state. In redux you copy state, and only then make your changes to the NEW object. You may need to read up some more on redux. Or maybe I'm simply not understanding what you're trying ti do.